# Atom: Multiple Cursors Cmd+Click

Tags: atom-editor

The latest update to `Atom v1.14.3` editor took away the ability to have multiple cursors via Cmd+Click. I'm on `macOS Sierra v10.12.3`.

Is there a way to enable multiple cursors?

Comment: Just updated the post with the version.

Comment: macOS Sierra 10.12.3

Comment: Oh, and now I've answered the wrong comment. Ignore that git remark (which I just deleted). I cannot reproduce this behavior using Atom 1.14.3 on macOS. Have you tried disabling some of your Atom packages and seeing if one of them is interfering with the cmd-click mapping? It is working as normal here.

Comment: Thank you! `nuclide 0.207.0` is the culprit.

Comment: Yep, uninstall nuclide and multi-cursor is back!

Comment: atom-ide-ui is the culprit too.
so I pull an issue, and they answerd soon. [here is it](https://github.com/facebook-atom/atom-ide-ui/issues/200#event-1556694785)

Comment: I met the same question,and i solve it by change Hyperclick in the settings of nuclide, it works for me. [Hyperclick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4BEM.png) Because Nuclide captures the cmd+click behavior for 'go to definition' by default.

Answer (score 0):

My box for "cmd-click for multi cursor" is checked in, but it doesn't work.
But, I discovered you can press cmd-shift and it makes cursors.